# ldapsearch - users in dynamic groups

Tags: linux, bash, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

I need to get all users from a dynamic group with ldapsearch.

I dont know what to look for, I only know how to do basic stuff.

What I got atm:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -D "user@domain" -w "password" -b "OU=org,OU=group,OU=ressources,OU=organisation,DC=domain,DC=local" -H "ldap://dc.domain.local" "CN=groupname" displayName info
```

This only shows me the groupname and description.

How do I list all the users in this group? I guess I have to check the users for the DN of this group but how?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
(memberOfCN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```